# How do I persist text from NSTextView back to Core data attribute when using binding?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

My Core Data Entity is following:

> Entity:Story
>
> ToMany relation to Note: notesOnStories
>
> Entity:Note
>
> attribute: note

In storyboard, the NStableView get data from NSStoryArrayController and the NSTextView shows comment which receives data from NSNoteArrayController using Content set from NSStoryArrayController.

*This is done using binding in storyboard.*
*NSTextView rich text formatting is disabled*

Now when I edits the note in NSTextView, and in the delegate method I make a save to Core Data.

```
-(void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)notification{

     NSError *error = nil;
            [self.mainContext save:&error];
            if(error){
                NSLog(@"ERROR SAVING MAIN MOC %@: %@:", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
}
```

**The problem is, next time when I launch my app, the strings are not save in the Note Entity**

When I perform save on moc, I am saving state of Core data model at that time than why does it not get saved to disk. Since NSTextView is showing Entity attribute current value.

Comment: When you set up the value binding, are you also checking the *Continuously Updates Value* option? If you're not, you should be.

Comment: @PaulPatterson, I now checked the Continuously Updates Value option in NSTextView bindings, still strings are not saving.

Comment: @PaulPatterson, It is now saving but not always, and when it does it only saves few word of the total input.

Comment: @PaulPatterson, The problem seems to be that when I placed saving method in -(void)applicationWillTerminate, the saving could not be completed in that time. Now I moved to different method and things are saving correctly. Continuously Updates Value did helped :)